# Why does 考 precede 中文 in 我下个星期要考中文?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

In my Chinese textbook, for a dialogue, one of the lines says "我下个星期要考中文". Why is 中文 after 考, shouldn't the sentence be "我下个星期要中文的考"?

Comment: 要+verb考+object中文, 考is not noun

Comment: `考中文考试` `to have a Chinese test` would also be acceptable phrasing. Perhaps it is the omission of 考试 (test) that is throwing you off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

考 is the verb.

> 我 / 下个星期 / 要 / 考 / 中文
>   I / next week / will / test / Chinese

If it helps, you could regard 考中文 here as a set construction meaning "to have a Chinese test". Same for 考数学 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 考 further back in your sentence, you might write:

我下周有汉语考试。Next week I have a Chinese exam.

汉语 Chinese language
考试 exam

Answer (score 1):

我下个星期要考中文
because in this sentence, 考 is a verb, 中文 is a noun.
do something after 要 (preposition)

In other word, 我下个星期有中文考试